# Equidistribution of returns and height of first peak of Dyck paths

Tags: reference-request, catalan-numbers, co.combinatorics

I believe that it is "well known" that the following two statistics on Dyck paths have symmetric joint distribution:

1. number of returns to the axis $RET(D)$
2. height of the first peak (or length of the last descent) $HFP(D)$

That is: $\sum_{D} x^{RET(D)}y^{HFP(D)} = \sum_{D} x^{HFP(D)}y^{RET(D)}$

However, I could not find a reference for that.  Might it be due to Kreweras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the article ["A bijection on Dyck paths and its consequences"](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0012-365X(97)00097-6) by E. Deutsch. The author has several papers on enumerative problems on Dyck/Motzkin paths. (See also [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0012-365X(98)00371-9))

Comment: Many thanks! I'll leave the question open for another day just in case somebody comes up with an earlier reference... 

Answer (score 1):

For future references: as we have discussed in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/131809#132013), this also follows from the "zeta map" sending the bistatistic (area,bounce) to the bistatistic (dinv,area). For another definition and further background, see also page 50 of [Jim Haglund's book](http://math.upenn.edu/~jhaglund/books/qtcat.pdf).